# Update column for few million rows in one table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to update two columns from one table which conatins few million rows. What is the most efficient way for doing this?

It will be something like this:

```
update my_table set column_one = to_date('11/11/11', 'RR/MM/DD'),
                    column_two = to_date('11/11/11', 'RR/MM/DD');
```

or this:

```
update my_table set column_one = to_date('11/11/11', 'RR/MM/DD');
update my_table set column_two = to_date('11/11/11', 'RR/MM/DD');
```

Or there is a better way?

Comment: Update both columns at the same time. But I suppose it would be a good idea to split it into several updates. (1000 rows per update perhaps?)

Comment: Read this: http://mysqlserverteam.com/multi-table-trick/

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam MySQL != Oracle.

Comment: Updating in one pass is best, and if the columns are indexed then drop the index first and rebuild it after rather than updating it on the fly too.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to update a table with million rows is not to perform update operation at all and rather create a new table with updated values.

> 1. Create a new table with updated columns while creation.
> 2. Notice all the Synonyms, Grants, Constraints, Indexes.
> 3. Drop the old table.
> 4. Rename new table to old table.
> 5. Recreated grants, synonyms, constraints, indexes.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Agree, not in all cases.

Comment: On an unrelated note, sometimes down votes don't make much sense to me!

Comment: A downvote usually means an answer was considered "not useful".

Comment: Thanks! I know that :) Was just thinking out loud.

Comment: In this case, it was because the answer was inappropriate for most scenarios. Duplicating the entire contents of a large table just to update two of its columns will only rarely be an efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new table, just break it up into chunks.

```
update my_table set column_one = to_date('11/11/11', 'RR/MM/DD'),
                    column_two = to_date('11/11/11', 'RR/MM/DD')
where rownum < 1000 
AND column_one <> to_date('11/11/11', 'RR/MM/DD')
AND column_two <> to_date('11/11/11', 'RR/MM/DD');
```

@Incognito's answer is probably more performant. Try this way if you're meaning for 'efficient' was less time spent on writing code.

Comment: How is this going to be more performant that just doing the update in one fell swoop? You're now adding context switching into the mix.

Comment: You misread the sentence '@Incognito's answer is probably more performant.'

Comment: No, I didn't - that's comparing apples with oranges. I'm asking why you would advocate chunking the update up vs just doing a straight update. Whether a straight update is faster than @Incognito's answer would need to be tested, but isn't relevant to my initial question.

Comment: @Boneist Because the OP asked about chunking, dude.

Comment: where did they ask about chunking? I can see jarlh mentioned chunking, but not the OP.

Comment: @Boneist Oh snap. I got all confused. I'm confused easily.

Comment: You and me both! *{:-)